# ES6 Module loader to resolve symbolic references

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

We are trying to create an ES6 loader to use symbolic references to modules instead of well formed URIs or paths in import sentences. For instances, an import like this one:

```
import { foo } from 'com.bussines.platform.utils';
```

should be resolve the symbolic reference `com.bussines.platform.utils` to a real uri and proceed with the regular loading process to get `foo`.

To achieve this goal we are using the `es-module-loader` [polyfill](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader)  developed by @guybedford. As, we are in the browser context, we have create a loader delegating to `BrowserESModuleLoader`:

```
class CustomBrowserLoader extends RegisterLoader {

  constructor(Loader) {
    super();
    this.loader = new BrowserESModuleLoader();
  }

  [RegisterLoader.resolve] (key) {
    let uri = Resolve (key)
    return this.loader[RegisterLoader.resolve] (uri); // (1)
  }

  [RegisterLoader.instantiate] (uri) {
    return this.loader[RegisterLoader.instantiate] (uri); // (2)
  }
}
```

The problem is that, surprisingly, calls at lines (1) and (2) doesn't find the required methods `resolve` and `instantiate`. We have tried other approaches based on inheritance but getting similar results.

¿Could anyone give some insights about how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders are separate builds, so I think you would want BrowserESModuleLoader.resolve and BrowserESModuleLoader.instantiate here.

It may be better though to directly fork the Browser ES Module Loader code itself, and adapt it to handle these types of specifiers directly instead.